# RichFaces 4 - Row Count of a Filtered ExtendedDataTable

Tags: richfaces

After applying a filter to an ExtendedDataTable how would I go about retrieving the new row count displayed to the user?

I have attempted to bind the ExtendedDataTable to a UIExtendedDataTable object within the backing bean, but I am unable to find a method/attribute that has this value.  I am only able to obtain the row count of the entire list before it has been filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, wrote a pure javascript solution using jQuery, get the row count of the result div class when the filter is complete. Let me know if you find a better solution.